# Criação de tags

Tags: debate, wikis-de-tags, privilégios

Criei uma tag sobre *traits*, mas diz que a edição precisa ser aprovada:

> Obrigado por sua edição!
>   Esta edição estará visível apenas para você até que seja analisada por um especialista.

1,500, aprovar edições do wiki de tag: Aprovar edições nos wikis de tag feitos por usuários regulares

1,250, criar sinônimos da tag: Decidir quais tags têm o mesmo significado que outras

---

Estes não seriam os privilégios de edição e criação de tags?

Comment: Aproveitando, vi sua sugestão e rejeitei o resumo, pois esses não aceitam Markdown nem HTML.

Comment: Por causa do `<sub>`?

Comment: Falei resumo, mas é o ***fragmento***: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17381

Comment: Desculpa ai mas realmente não entendi - sou muito noob no SO.

Comment: Eu rejeitei a edição. *Trait* é um recursos disponível em diversas linguagens. A descrição como foi feita levaria as pessoas entenderem errado o uso da *tag*. Você tem que descrever como a *tag* deve ser usada e não podemos deixar ela exclusiva para o PHP.

Comment: Entendi. *php-trait* entra?

Comment: Isto que vc colocou no fragmento não renderiza `[**Traits**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.traits.php)`, vai aparecer tal qual.

Comment: Sorry, não sabia.

Comment: Não seria ideal ter uma *tag* para cada função de cada linguagem, criaria uma matriz muito grande de *tags*. Imagine que todas vez que alguém for falar de *trait* de uma linguagem, tenha que criar uma *tag* só para isto, fica mais difícil achar alguma coisa, e perde o sentido em usar várias *tags*, porque no fundo só uma importaria mesmo. O problema não é a *tag* e sim a descrição dela.

Comment: Entendi. A tag [namespace](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/namespace/info) fornece uma descrição bem genérica e ao final do texto uma descrição do uso em C++. Acredito que poderia conter um exemplo em PHP. O mesmo seria com a Trait - uma descrição genérica e um exemplo para linguagens individualmente?

Comment: Poderia mas achei um outro problema na *tag* que acho que ele precisaria ser removida para dar lugar à correta. Por padrão a preferência seria usar no singular a não ser que houvesse um motivo para estar no plural. O conceito chama-se apenas *trait*. Como o as *tags* são muito parecidas, acho que só um moderador poderia trocar, ou pior, teria que apagar esta, e amanhã colocar a nova correta, vou ver isto.

Comment: Há algo que eu possa fazer? Devo remover a tag?

Comment: Aguarde, um moderador pode ter uma solução melhor.

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/300/diretrizes-para-cria%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-tag-wikis

Comment: Editei o tag wiki para servir em qualquer linguagem, porém mantendo o exemplo em PHP. Também criei uma tag no singular, e deixei o plural como sinônimo (CC @bigown)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não, esse privilégio é de [Usuários Confiáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (4k num site beta, 20k num graduado):

> Os usuários confiáveis podem realizar ações de confiança, incluindo:
>
> - Votar para excluir respostas com pontuação de -1 ou inferior
> - Votar para cancelar a exclusão de respostas, exceto as que foram excluídas por um moderador
> - Votar para excluir perguntas com uma pontuação de -3 ou inferior imediatamente após seu encerramento
> - **Editar wikis de tags sem necessidade de aprovação**

Com os 1.500 é só para aprovar sugestões na fila de análise, e não aparece o botão <kbd>Editar</kbd>.

Comment: Beleza, então ainda falta :)

Comment: Vixi, e quando sair do beta (nem idéia) vai faltar mais ainda :P

Comment: Não tem problema, enquanto isso vamos dando trabalho pra vocês :)